# Unable to delete specific records using temp tables and using not in operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-delete

```
create table demo11 (dn int, rn varchar(max))
insert into demo11 values(1,'A'),(1,'A-1'),(1,'A-3'),(2,'A'),(2,'B'),(2,'C'),(3,'A-3'),(3,'A-4'),(4,'A'),(4,'A-1'),(4,'A-2'),(4,'A-5')
    
    DROP TABLE #dnrn
    CREATE TABLE #dnrn(dn int,rn VARCHAR(MAX))
    insert into #dnrn(dn,rn)
    SELECT dn AS dn, MAX(rn) AS rn FROM demo11 GROUP BY dn
    SELECT * FROM #dnrn 
    delete from demo11 where dn NOT IN (SELECT dn FROM #dnrn) AND rn NOT IN (SELECT rn FROM #dnrn)
    SELECT * FROM demo11
```

Tried with above query but didnot got desired result

Expected result : demo11 should consists of only max revision record group by dn

Output should be : (1 A-3), (2 C), (3 A-4), (4, A-5)

Comment: what's the output ur getting?

Comment: delete from demo11 where dn NOT IN (SELECT dn FROM #dnrn) AND rn NOT IN (SELECT rn FROM #dnrn) 

The above query is not deleting any records ( 0 rows are affected)

Comment: iiuc, select dn will bring all dn records and hence there will no deletion. ur query is wrong. [1,2,3,4] is going to be present any day in ur temp table.

Comment: you have these options -
1. delete demo11 and rename temp table as demo11.
2. delete from demo11 where rn NOT IN (SELECT rn FROM #dnrn). Since, a value of dn is always going to be present in temp table. you had better of be doing comparison on rn column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have each `dn` from `demo11` in the temporary table, so `dn NOT IN (SELECT dn FROM #dnrn)` is false for every row in `demo11` and thus no row gets deleted.

You can achieve what you want to do when you join a derived table (there's no need for a temporary table) which uses the `row_number()` window function to a assign numbers for the values of `rn` per `dn` value and then filer for all rows where this number isn't `1`, which designates the maximum.

```
DELETE d
       FROM demo11 AS d
            INNER JOIN (SELECT dn,
                               rn,
                               row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY dn
                                                  ORDER BY rn DESC) r
                               FROM demo11) AS x
                       ON d.dn = x.dn
                          AND d.rn = x.rn
       WHERE x.r <> 1;
```

Comment: No need for any join. `delete t from (select row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY dn ORDER BY rn DESC) as r  from demo11) t where r > 1` should work

Comment: Thanks @MartinSmith it is working correctly.